# Push a bare git repository to another remote?

Tags: git

I have cloned a git repository using:

```
git clone --mirror http://example.com/some-big-repo.git
```

Then I have removed a bunch of binaries using:
https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

I would now like to push the resulting repository to a new remote. I have added another remote:

```
git remote add other http://example.com/new-repo
```

And next I would do:

```
git push other
```

But is that safe to do? I really need to NOT modify the repository I originally cloned from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah that should work. If you want to play it safe you can use this

```
git push --repo=other
```

From the docs:

> **--repo=>repository<**
>
> This option is equivalent to the  argument. If both are specified, the command-line argument takes
>   precedence.

---

> **>repository<**
>
> The "remote" repository that is destination of a push
>   operation. This parameter can be either a URL (see the section GIT
>   URLS below) or the name of a remote (see the section REMOTES below).

Also read http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: Ok it seems to work, I just need to use the -all command to make sure all branches are psuhed. And the original repository does not seem to be affected.

Comment: @u123 *And the original repository does not seem to be affected.* that is what is important here